# Java: Advise on Charset Conversion

Tags: java, character-encoding, data-conversion

I have been working on a scenario that does the following:

1. Get input data in Unicode format; [UTF-8]
2. Convert to ISO-8559;
3. Detect & replace unsupported characters for encoding; [Based on user-defined key-value pairs]

My question is, I have been trying to find information on ISO-8559 in depth with no luck yet. Has anybody happen to know more about this? How different is this one from ISO-8859? Any details will be much helpful.

Secondly, keeping the ISO-8559 requirement aside, I went ahead to write my program to convert the incoming data to ISO-8859 in Java. While I am able to achieve what is needed using character based replacement, it obviously seem to be time-consuming when data size is huge. [in MBs]

I am sure there must be a better way to do this. Can someone advise me, please?

Comment: [ISO 8559](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=15821) seems to be related to a different field.

Comment: it appears so. I found more about ISO-8559 [HERE](http://actuel.fr.selfhtml.org/archives/docu/7.0/thb.htm)

Comment: @Srii: no, that's a simple (but very consistent!) typo. And I'm pretty sure that whoever gave you that task made a typo as well. ISO-8559 has nothing to do with character sets, while ISO-8859 is a very common specification in that area. I'd bet real money that they *meant* ISO-8859.

Comment: the 2nd link appears to be talking about 8859. is it because of the french number system? ha!

Comment: I suspect its `ISO-8859-1` which the OP is talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: Thank you, Joachim, irreputable & Peter. Any tips for mu question two? In case, if it turns out be a typo, I can then have a better response. :)

Comment: Another [source](http://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding/) mentions the following:
_italic_Characteristics: ISO 8559 is an 8 bit system that groups various alphabets into parts, which are then named 8859-1, 8859-2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to convert UTF-8 to ISO-8859 ***-1***, that is Western Latin-1. There are many char set tables in the net.

1. In general for web browsers and Windows, it would be better to convert to **Windows-1252**, which is an extension redefining the range 0x80 - 0xBF, undermore with special quotes as seen in MS Word. Browsers are defacto capable to interprete these codes in an ISO-559-1 even on a Mac.
2. Java standard conversion like `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("..."), "Windows-1252")` does already much. You can either write a kind of filter, or find introduced `?` untranslated special characters. You could translate latin letters with accents not in Windows-1252 as ASCII letters:

   ```
       String s = ...
       s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
       return s = s.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}", "");
   ```
3. For other scripts like Hindi or Cyrillic the keyword to search for is **transliteration**.

Comment: Thanks Joop, The normalizer class seems to replace all DiacriticalMarks while I would like to replace only a set of few characters, based on the property file linked to the program. The question marks, produced a result of translation failure, becomes a common symbol and hence the property file containing value-to-be-replaced-&-value-to-be-replaced-with becomes invalid. 

For eg: if data contains, SÄSöSÄSöS, the translation may result like this: S?S?S?S?S. The equation defined in property file, Ä=A & ö=o implementation becomes almost difficult. May be I am wrong, but I am glad to be corrected.

Comment: +1 From the european point of view: The biggest downside of `ISO-8859-1` is that it does not contain the `€` Symbol. But `Windows-1252` does.

Comment: @FabianBarney: as does ISO-8859-15.

Comment: I did not come up with actual code, as its tricky. First replace '?', then translate; where '?' appears look for the original char, and replace that with the ASCII version and restore the original question marks. This would leave in `ç` (Latin-1) but not `ĉ` (Latin-3, UTF-8).

Comment: @JoachimSauer good point mentioning ISO-8859-15. Though HTML pages with ISO-8859-15 will not show the 128-159 range of Windows-1252, which ISO-8859-1 will (illegally) show. Like comma-style quotes.

Comment: @JoopEggen, Thanks. This is once again a character-based-replacement. Right? From a performance view-point, how different could this impose in processing? Any comments?

Comment: @Srii, yes character based, and one has to pay attention to make it optimal.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate all your responses.